# HtmlAgilityPack Drops Option End Tags

Tags: html, parsing, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack.  I create an HtmlDocument and LoadHtml with the following string:

```
<select id="foo_Bar" name="foo.Bar"><option selected="selected" value="1">One</option><option value="2">Two</option></select>
```

This does some unexpected things.  First, it gives two parser errors, EndTagNotRequired.  Second, the select node has 4 children - two for the option tags and two more for the inner text of the option tags.  Last, the OuterHtml is like this:

```
<select id="foo_Bar" name="foo.Bar"><option selected="selected" value="1">One<option value="2">Two</select>
```

So basically it is deciding for me to drop the closing tags on the options.  Let's leave aside for a moment whether it is proper and desirable to do that.  I am using HtmlAgilityPack to test HTML generation code, so I don't want it to make any decision for me or give any errors unless the HTML is truly malformed.  Is there some way to make it behave how I want?  I tried setting some of the options for HtmlDocument, specifically:

```
 doc.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = false;
 doc.OptionCheckSyntax = false;
 doc.OptionFixNestedTags = false;
```

This is not working.  If HtmlAgilityPack cannot do what I want, can you recommend something that can?

Comment: for anyone else facing this issue, see my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759355/image-tag-not-closing-with-htmlagilitypack/12096383#12096383 for a method of setting bobnce's answer without modifying the HAP source.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The exact same error is reported on the HAP home page's discussion, but it looks like no meaningful fixes have been made to the project in a few years. Not encouraging.

A quick browse of the source suggests the error might be fixable by commenting out line 92 of HtmlNode.cs:

```
// they sometimes contain, and sometimes they don 't...
ElementsFlags.Add("option", HtmlElementFlag.Empty);
```

(Actually no, they always contain label text, although a blank string would also be valid text. A careless author might omit the end-tag, but then that's true of any element.)

**ADD**

An equivalent solution is calling `HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");` before any use of liberary (without need to modify the liberary source code)

Comment: I ran into this problem while trying to get option's InnerText value. I applied your solution directly in my code using HtmlNode's exposed static HashTable:

HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");

Comment: Hi Jason, how did you actually solve this problem directly in your own code?  I tried HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option"); in my code but it didn't solve the un-closing img tag issue?  Could you give me details please, I don't want to modify and recompile the source unless I have to.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ray247 I tried this `HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");` once at static constructor and `EndTagNotRequired` errors disappeared

Answer (score 5):

It seems that there is some reason not to parse the Option tag as a "generic" tag, for XHTML compliance, however this can be a real pain in the neck.

My suggestion is to do a whole-string-replace and change all "option" tags to "my_option" tags, that way you:

1. Don't have to modify the source of the library (and can upgrade it later).
2. Can parse as you usually would.

The original post on HtmlAgilityPack forum can be found at:
http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=14982