# HTML Selector Library

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, html, jquery-selectors

Do any jQuery-like html element selector libraries exist in the Dot Net world? I am building an application which involves huge amount of html parsing.

Say I want to enumerate all 'href's and 'src's inside only a selected 'div's having its id like "post_message_%". 
Or say want to select the name and value strings within a form with a specific id or input type(eg. hidden or radio)

I can write the code..but first looking for any existing solution, so that I can use it and save my time for something else.

Comment: There is HTML Agility Pack or Sgml Reader. You can use XPath query syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check out the Html Agility pack, available [here](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).
Here's a use case from their website, that uses XPATH selectors:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm");
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
{
   HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
   att.Value = FixLink(att);
}
doc.Save("file.htm");
```

Comment: Agility Pack, Yes I heard this name. Thanks for the quick reply, I am checking right now... Any more suggestions are welcome...

Comment: @PrasenjitChatterjee, I've researched the matter about a month ago, and HtmlAgilityPack was the best option, which I frankly didn't like as much as BeautifulSoup, which is sadly only available only for Python. I'm not sure if it works with IronPython, but if you have time do check it out.

Comment: Thanks, I used python before and familiar with the syntax and style...But mainly I worked on 3.x versions...Unfortunately all these libraries still use the 2.x version..but I will definitely keep it in mind..If possible on the later version of my product I will incorporate it.

Comment: I just finished writing my code...it looks so elegant and tidy.....Previously I was using regex and it was a big headache..Thanks very much for the help..

Comment: There's issues with HAP though in that it can't deal with XHTML style self closing tags http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759355/image-tag-not-closing-with-htmlagilitypack

Comment: @MatthewLock - They say to never use Regex to parse HTML. Since writing this answer 2 years ago, I've actually gone back to regex. HAP is not fool-proof by any means, and regex does get convoluted quite quick. YMMV. There's a way to hook-in chrome to re-tag the page, by the way, then regex becomes the natural choice.

Comment: I hear that. Often regex is quick and simple. Check out CsQuery thought that doesn't seem to have such a problem mangling the HTML document as HAP does, and the syntax is nice like jQuery.

Answer (score 6):

A little late to the game, but here's another alternative. [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/csquery) is a complete port of jQuery in .NET4. It's on NuGet as `CsQuery`. It's stable and feature complete, including all CSS3 selectors and DOM manipulation methods. It's also fully indexed, making selectors orders of magnitude faster than HTML Agility Pack.

The syntax looks like this (copying example above)

```
CQ doc = CQ.CreateFromFile("file.htm");
foreach (IDomObject link in doc["a"]) {
    var attr = link["href"];
    link["href"] = FixLink(attr);
}
```

The property indexer syntax for a `CQ` object is the same as the default jQuery method to run a selector, e.g. `$('a')`. On a `DomObject` (an element) it returns the attribute value.

In addition to CSS selectors, CsQuery also implements all the jQuery methods, so you could do this as:

```
doc.Each((i,e)=> {
    var el = CQ.Create(e);   // or shorthand: var el = e.Cq()
    el.Attr("href",FixLink(el.Attr("href"))
});
```

The syntax `e.Cq()` is the C# version of wrapping an element in a jQuery object, like `var el = $(e)`. Since the value of the $ syntax is its brevity, and there's no way to create a default static method in C#, a method `Cq()` on elements is provided as shorthand to wrap an element in a `CQ` object.