# removing node from html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am Using `HtmlAgilityPack` for parsing html document , now when i replace or remove any child element like :

```
        string TargetPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Views/SaveChange"),
        User.Identity.Name + "Test.cshtml");

        HtmlDocument ndoc = new HtmlDocument();
        ndoc.Load(TargetPath);

        ndoc.DocumentNode.RemoveChild(ndoc.GetElementbyId("id"), false);
        ndoc.save(TargetPath);
```

After doing this when i open my Test.cshtml file then all closing tags become unclose , like

```
before removing child => <img .. />
after removing child => <img ..>
```

Can any body tell me whats the problem here?

Comment: try this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759355/image-tag-not-closing-with-htmlagilitypack

Comment: thanks @lekso , i got my answer