# HtmlAgilityPack Drops Paragraph End Tags

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I just wrote a simple console application to see if I was crazy

```
       var html = "<div class=\"page\"><x></x></div>";

        HtmlDocument doc2 = new HtmlDocument();
        doc2.LoadHtml(html);
        var pageNodes2 = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'page')]");

        foreach (var pageNode in pageNodes2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pageNode.InnerHtml);
        }
```

and the output is

```
   <x></x>
```

but if the `x` is replaced by `<p>` the output becomes

```
    <p>
```

how can I solve it ?

Comment: I just added it

Comment: It's a know issue, there are a couple of workarounds in the link to the question above and [in this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759355/image-tag-not-closing-with-htmlagilitypack/12096383#12096383).