# HtmlAgilityPack invalid markup

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am using the HtmlAgilityPack from codeplex.
When I pass a simple html string into it and then get the resulting html back,
it cuts off tags.

Example:

```
string html = "<select><option>test</option></select>";
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);

var result = d.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;

// result gives me:
<select><option>test</select>
```

So the closing tag for the option is missing. Am I missing a setting or using this wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by commenting out line 92 of HtmlNode.cs in the source, compiled and it worked like a charm.

```
ElementsFlags.Add("option", HtmlElementFlag.Empty); // comment this out
```

Found the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293342/htmlagilitypack-drops-option-end-tags) question

Comment: You don't need to comment it out... `ElementsFlags` is  publicly visible field.  Just remove the key prior to loading the HTML.  `HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");`

Answer (score 0):

In HTML the  tag has no end tag.

In XHTML the  tag must be properly closed.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

"There is also no adherence to XHTML or XML" - [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

This could be why? My guess is that if the tag is optional, the Agility Pack will leave it off. Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you know of a way to set a property that signals to the HtmlDocument settings to be XHTML rather than HTML?

Comment: I got lost on this one. @lloydhanneman16 could you please explain why did you say that `In HTML the tag has no end tag.`?

Comment: @Icarus - because that's what the w3schools page says. It is, as is usual for w3schools, talking nonsense.

Comment: @Alochi I didn't bother reading the W3schools website. Now I see where lloydhanneman16 is coming from... thanks.

Comment: Is it not true that in HTML the <option> tag doesn't require a closing tag?