# Drop down missing closing option tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sitecore

I have a drop down list but the closing option tags are missing. This causes the site to fail W3C Validation against XHTML 1.1

This is my HTML:

```
<select>
    <option value="">Select...
    <option value="val1">Value One
    <option value="val2">Value Two
</select>
```

where I expect this:

```
<select>
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="val1">Value One</option>
    <option value="val2">Value Two</option>
</select>
```

I have tried both `HtmlSelect` and `DropDownList`. I have tried adding `ListItem` and databinding in order to populate it but I get the same HTML every time.

Any idea what might be causing this?

**EDIT**

I'm using .NET 3.5, the site is a Sitecore site.

This is my doctype declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

Populating like this:

```
HtmlSelect dropdown = new HtmlSelect();
dropdown.ID = _Data.ControlID;

List<DataCollectionItem> lisItemCollection = new List<DataCollectionItem>();

foreach (DataCollectionItem item in lisItemCollection)
    dropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.Text, item.Value));
```

Have tried this too, with the same outcome:

```
dropdown.DataSource = lisItemCollection;
dropdown.DataTextField = "Text";
dropdown.DataValueField = "Value";
dropdown.DataBind();
```

Browser files:

Form.browser

```
<browsers>
  <browser refID="Default">
    <controlAdapters>
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm" adapterType="Sitecore.Web.FormAdapter, Sitecore.Kernel" />
    </controlAdapters>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

w3cValidator.browser

```
<browsers> 
  <!--  Browser capability file for the w3c validator 
        sample UA: "W3C_Validator/1.305.2.148 libwww-perl/5.803" 
  --> 
  <browser id="w3cValidator" parentID="default"> 
    <identification> 
      <userAgent match="^W3C_Validator" /> 
    </identification> 

    <capture> 
      <userAgent match="^W3C_Validator/(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(?'minor'\.\d+)\w*).*" /> 
    </capture> 

    <capabilities> 
      <capability name="browser" value="w3cValidator" /> 
      <capability name="majorversion" value="${major}" /> 
      <capability name="minorversion" value="${minor}" /> 
      <capability name="version" value="${version}" /> 
      <capability name="w3cdomversion" value="1.0" /> 
      <capability name="xml" value="true" /> 
      <capability name="tagWriter" value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" /> 
    </capabilities> 
  </browser> 
</browsers>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to generate the markup?

Comment: My guess is you are using a (very) old version of ASP.NET. What version is it?

Comment: Did you look in the App_Browsers folder of your application ? There could be a .browser file in there declaring a custom adapter which overrides your DDL and HtmlSelect.

Comment: Why won't you just add those manually at source view?

Comment: Do you have proper doctype in pages example <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC 
   "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">   and App_Browsers folder exists in your root folder as mentioned by jbl

Comment: All questions answered in my edit. I didn't post the code as it's the type of code I've written a thousand times with no problems - the issue must therefore lie somewhere else! Is there anything in my browser files that looks like it could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was due to the HTML Agility pack.

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447461/htmlagilitypack-invalid-markup) for more details.