# Parent of htmlagilitypack text node is select instead of option?

Tags: html-agility-pack

Using htmlagility, I am searching for text nodes in a dom structure consisting of a select.

```
<select>
  <option>
    one
  </option>
  <option>
    two
  </option>
</select>
```

Those nodes parents seems to be the

```
<select>
```

instead of an

```
<option>
```

Why?

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Foo.Test
{
  [TestClass]
  public class HtmlAgilityTest
  {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestTraverseTextNodesInSelect()
    {
      var html = "<select><option>one</option><option>two</option></select>";

      var doc = new HtmlDocument();
      doc.Load(new StringReader(html));

      var elements = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(n=>n.Name == "#text");

      Assert.AreEqual(2, elements.Count());
      Assert.AreEqual("select", elements.ElementAt(0).ParentNode.Name);
      Assert.AreEqual("select", elements.ElementAt(1).ParentNode.Name);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It will be clear why HAP worked that way if you can see how HAP read that HTML : `Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [HtmlAgilityPack drop closing `<option>` tag by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293342/htmlagilitypack-drops-option-end-tags). HAP sees your HTML like this :

```
Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
//result :
//<select><option>one<option>two</select>
```

And as mentioned in the linked question above, you can alter that behavior by calling following line before initiating the `HtmlDocument` :

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");
```

Comment: Do you know how <option> did end up in that list of auto closing tags?

Comment: Set as solved because of the link, hard to choose which answer that is the best

Answer (score 2):

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void TestTraverseTextNodesInSelect()
    {
      HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");
      var html = "<select><option>one</option><option>two</option></select>";

      var doc = new HtmlDocument();
      doc.Load(new StringReader(html));

      var elements = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(n=>n.Name == "#text");

      Assert.AreEqual(2, elements.Count());
      Assert.AreEqual("select", elements.ElementAt(0).ParentNode.Name);
      Assert.AreEqual("select", elements.ElementAt(1).ParentNode.Name);
    }
```

you can try with this.

In the library it has like this. You need to remove it. by default the AgilityPack is set to treat option tags as empty.

```
ElementsFlags.Add("option", HtmlElementFlag.Empty);
```