# Parsing from HTML file using HtnlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I have an HTML (DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional) file generated by Oracle Reports.

Here is source of HTML file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD><META content="IE=5.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">

<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<META name="GENERATOR" content="MSHTML 11.00.9600.17801"></HEAD>
<BODY dir="LTR" bgcolor="#ffffff"> <!-- Created by Oracle Reports  --> 
<TABLE width="960" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <TBODY>
  <TR valign="top">
    <TD height="9">
    <TD width="71" rowspan="3" colspan="3"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><B><TT>Date</TT></B></FONT><BR>
    <TD>
    <TD width="89" rowspan="3" colspan="3"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><B><TT>Target Number</TT></B></FONT>   
    <TD>
    <TD width="143" rowspan="3" colspan="7"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><B><TT>Description</TT></B></FONT>   
    <TD colspan="11">
    <TD width="101" rowspan="3" colspan="4"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><B><TT>Transaction </TT></B></FONT><BR><FONT face="Courier New" size="1"><B><TT>Sum</TT></B></FONT><BR>
    <TD colspan="2">
    <TD width="89" rowspan="3"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><B><TT>Fee</TT></B></FONT>   
    <TD>
    <TD width="113" rowspan="3" colspan="4"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><B><TT>Sum</TT></B></FONT>   
    <TD>
    <TD width="137" rowspan="3" colspan="2"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><B><TT>Device </TT></B></FONT><BR><FONT face="Courier New" size="1"><B><TT>Id</TT></B></FONT><BR>
    <TD>
  <TR valign="top">
    <TD height="9">
    <TD>
    <TD>
    <TD colspan="3">
    <TD width="40" colspan="5"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><B><TT>Reference</TT></B></FONT>   
    <TD colspan="3">
    <TD colspan="2">
    <TD>
    <TD>
    <TD>
  <TR valign="top">
    <TD height="9">
    <TD>
    <TD>
    <TD colspan="11">
    <TD colspan="2">
    <TD>
    <TD>
    <TD>
  <TR valign="top">
    <TD height="9">
    <TD width="71" rowspan="2" colspan="3"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><TT>03/09/2015</TT></FONT>   
    <TD>
    <TD width="89" rowspan="2" colspan="3"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><TT>4405641418</TT></FONT>   
    <TD>
    <TD width="143" rowspan="2" colspan="7"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><TT>WWW.EXAMPLE.COM</TT></FONT>   
    <TD>
    <TD width="71" rowspan="2" colspan="9"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><TT>524601231313</TT></FONT>   
    <TD>
    <TD width="101" rowspan="2" colspan="4"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><TT> 1 087,00</TT></FONT>   
    <TD colspan="2">
    <TD width="89" rowspan="2"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><TT>-26,09</TT></FONT>   
    <TD>
    <TD width="113" rowspan="2" colspan="4"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><TT> 1 060,91</TT></FONT>   
    <TD>
    <TD width="137" rowspan="2" colspan="2"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><TT>11055700</TT></FONT>   
    <TD>
  <TR valign="top">
    <TD height="9">
    <TD>
    <TD>
    <TD>
    <TD>
    <TD colspan="2">
    <TD>
    <TD>
    <TD>
  <TR>
    <TD height="5" colspan="43">
  <TR valign="top">
    <TD height="9">
    <TD width="71" rowspan="2" colspan="3"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><TT>03/09/2015</TT></FONT>   
    <TD>
    <TD width="89" rowspan="2" colspan="3"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><TT>4405641418</TT></FONT>   
    <TD>
    <TD width="143" rowspan="2" colspan="7"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><TT>WWW.EXAMPLE.COM</TT></FONT>   
    <TD>
    <TD width="71" rowspan="2" colspan="9"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><TT>524601231313</TT></FONT>   
    <TD>
    <TD width="101" rowspan="2" colspan="4"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><TT> 55,00</TT></FONT>   
    <TD colspan="2">
    <TD width="89" rowspan="2"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><TT>-1,32</TT></FONT>   
    <TD>
    <TD width="113" rowspan="2" colspan="4"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><TT> 53,68</TT></FONT>   
    <TD>
    <TD width="137" rowspan="2" colspan="2"><FONT face="Courier New" 
      size="1"><TT>11055700</TT></FONT>   
    <TD>


</BODY></HTML>
```

I need to parse that HTML to my C# entities using HTML agility pack. I'm not able to access `TT` tag in `TD` tag.

Here is C# code:

```
var tds = DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body").SelectNodes("//tr[td[contains(@width,'71') and contains(@colspan,'3')]]").Descendants("tt");
```

How Can I access a `TT` tag?

Comment: Please the next time you want help. Could please just show an accurate and small representative of what your html file instead of this where there is a lot of redundancy. Because nobody wants to read all that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Kent is on to something, your document has a lot of unclosed `<td>` tags and that will cause issues when parsing. I suppose there is a reason even oracle is forcing this to render in IE5 compatible mode.

When looking in the debugger you will see that the HtmlAgilityPack has added a whole lot of close tags to the end of the document (check `doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml` in the debugger):

```
</td></td></td></td></td></td></td></td></td></td></td></td></td></td></td>
</td></td></tr></td></tr></td></td></td></td></td></td></td></td></td></tr>
</td></td></td></td></td></td></td></td></td></td></td></td></td></td></td>
</td></td></tr></td></td></td></td></td></td></td></td></tr></td></td></td>
</td></td></td></td></td></td></td></tr></td></td></td></td></td></td></td>
</td></td></td></td></td></td></td></td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>
```

These aren't closed where they're supposed to be... Unfortunately, the `OptionFixNestedTags` is turned on by default and it doesn't seem to influence the parser, as it does need to close these tags. neither does `OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = false`.

The next issue you're facing is that the `SelectSingleNode` and `SelectNodes` methods return `null`, not an empty collection, so your code will start throwing nullreference exceptions like crazy when anything is not found (which is probably the case in your code, at least it does that in my little test project). If you're using C#6 you can at least use `?.` to pre-empt the exception, but that won't fix the search code.

Then you're first calling `SelectSingleNode("//body")` followed by `.SelectNodes("//...")`, that second call should not use `//` which is anchored at the document root, but should use `.//` to be anchored below the body tag. as it is you might as well remove the `SelectSingleNode("//body")` call.

Due to the nesting issues, the Xpath won't find any `td`'s directly under `tr` it seems which fit your description. That is because as far as the Agility Pack is concerted, the `td` you're looking for is a child of the `td` that precedes it

This is the structure as it is read:

```
<TR valign="top">
    <TD height="9">
        <TD width="71" rowspan="3" colspan="3"><FONT face="Courier New" 
        size="1"><B><TT>Date</TT></B></FONT><BR>

            <TD></td>
        </td>
    </td>
</tr>
```

So in order to find your `tt` tags, you'll have to resort to:

```
var tds = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body//tr//td[@width=71 and @colspan=3]");
```

> Note that I also simplified the attribute lookups, as `contains` will cause issues if there are any `callspan=33` or `width=171` for example.

Your best action is to probably go back to the source of the report and query the database directly. Or fix the document first by closing any empty `<td>`'s before further parsing them.

There may be ways of changing the parser to detect `td` and `tr` differently, using by changing the ElementFlags for the node before loading the document, but my attempts have all met the same issues as you're already encountering.

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("td");
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Add("td", HtmlElementFlag.Closed | HtmlElementFlag.Empty);
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("tr");
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Add("tr", HtmlElementFlag.Closed);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/293357/736079

Answer (score 2):

If it is only the TT-tags you want.

```
HtmlNodeCollection tds = DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body[@dir='LTR']//table//tbody//tr//td//tt");
```

Should give you all the TT-tags.
Next time could you give a shorter and more concrete HTML-file. This one doesn't have ending tages for Table or tbody.

Also I think that you have to set the option for nested tags to true or else it will ignore td and tt tags.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags=true;
```

Comment: +1 on the request for a small and easy to test reproduction as part of the question. Plus any setup code done to the `HtmlDocument`object before calling `SelectNodes`.