# HtmlAgilityPack produces missing closing tags in OuterHtml

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack to parse and manipulate html text. However it seems the DocumentNode.OuterHtml gives missing closing tags.

*To isolate the issue now I am doing nothing else just parse and get the OuterHtml (no manipulation):*

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(myHtml);
result = document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

Original: (myHtml)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" /><title>
     MyTitle
</title>
```

OutputHtml: (result) **Notice that meta element is not closed**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"><title>
    MyTitle
</title>
```

Similarly all input and img elements are leaved open. (Please do not answer that it should not be a problem. Well it should not be, but it is.) Chrome can not render the page correctly. Keep reading.

What is more weird:

Original: (myHtml)

```
    <option value="10">Afrikaans</option>
    <option value="11">Albanian</option>
    <option value="12">Arabic</option>
    <option value="13">Armenian</option>
    <option value="14">Azerbaijani</option>
    <option value="15">Basque</option>
```

OutputHtml: (result) **Notice that that complete explicit closing tags are missing**

```
    <option value="10">Afrikaans
    <option value="11">Albanian
    <option value="12">Arabic
    <option value="13">Armenian
```

Using HtmlAgilitPack latest NuGet package: id="HtmlAgilityPack" version="1.4.9"

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293342/htmlagilitypack-drops-option-end-tags help? Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759355/image-tag-not-closing-with-htmlagilitypack ?

Comment: Thanks again. Yes  document.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true helped. Embarrasing I shoot a duplicate alike. Anyway still seems to be weird to me: The original html is correct so there should not be necessary any "auto" magic thing not to ruin it.

Comment: and in case you would like to write it as answer I will accept i.t

Comment: OK, thanks, will write it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options that you can set when you are loading the document.

**[OptionAutoCloseOnEnd](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlDocument/F/OptionAutoCloseOnEnd)**

Defines if closing for non closed nodes must be done at the end or directly in the document. Setting this to true can actually change how browsers render the page.

```
document = new HtmlDocument();
document.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;
document.LoadHtml(content);
```

Related sources worth reading:

[HtmlAgilityPack Drops Option End Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293342/htmlagilitypack-drops-option-end-tags)

[Image tag not closing with HTMLAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759355/image-tag-not-closing-with-htmlagilitypack)