# C# HTMLAgilityPack System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I can get the following to work in .Net Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xd8pO1

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var html =
        "<select class=\"vui-input d2l-select\" name=\"roleid\" id=\"z_d\" title=\"Role\"><option value=\"0\" selected=\"selected\">-- Select a Role --<option value=\"104\">Instructor<option value=\"105\">Student<option value=\"106\">TA 1<option value=\"107\">TA 2<option value=\"108\">TA 3<option value=\"109\">TA 4<option value=\"114\">TA 5<option value=\"115\">TA 6<option value=\"111\">Course Developer</select>";

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

        string name = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                        .SelectNodes("//*[text()[contains(., 'Instructor')]]").First().Attributes["value"].Value;

        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}
```

However, it does not work when I try to run it in my .Net application or in a new console application.

I get the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=DELETE
  StackTrace:
   at Program.Main() in E:\...........:line 18
```

I've tested to make sure the source is correctly formatted. Replacing line 18 with the following works:

```
string name = `htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select/option[@value=104]")
.First()
.Attributes["value"].Value;`
```

Any ideas why this is working in .Net Fiddle but not in my c# application in Visual Studio?

Comment: Use the debugger to determine what variable or property is null.

Comment: Break that huge XPath expression into separate expressions and test each one.

Comment: @Igor I'm getting, "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttributeCollection.this[string].get returned null.". But it doesn't return null when I test in .Net Fiddle link in OP

Answer (score 0):

I did some more searching and found this: [HtmlAgilityPack produces missing closing tags in OuterHtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179687/htmlagilitypack-produces-missing-closing-tags-in-outerhtml/35180911)

It looks like HTMLAgilityPack had an issue with parsing  tags where it removed the closing tag. I've updated my HTMLAgilityPack version to the latest and it is working now.