# Modify HTML content saved in a DB table

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-parsing

I have a table in DB with a general text field which contains HTML formatted text. I need to parse the content of such a field, find all the "img" tags and perform 2 operations (only for "img" tags):

1) Remove the "style" attribute with all its values.
2) Insert a class="img-responsive" attribute.

One characteristic of the HTML content to be parsed is that it does not have the complete hierarchy. For example, a string to be parse can be as follows:

```
<div>
<p>This is some text</p>
<img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/myImage.jpg" alt = "" style="width:600px; height: 400px;"/>
</div>
```

I have tried different ways to find the "img" tag without success. For example:

```
String strHTML = "The sample HTML code above";
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(strHTML);
foreach (var img in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img"))
{
    // Remove "style" attribute for "img" tag.
    // Add class="img-responsive" for "img" tag.
}
```

The problem with the code above is that there is not a root node but I do not know how to "override" such a node and parse the string directly.

Comment: Please tag the question with the language you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I found using the agility pack HTML.

```
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var html = @"<div>
                         <p>This is some text</p>
                         <img src=""http://www.mywebsite.com/myImage1.jpg"" alt = """" style=""width:600px; height: 400px;""/>
                         <img src=""http://www.mywebsite.com/myImage2.jpg"" alt = """" style=""width:600px; height: 400px;""/>
                         <img src=""http://www.mywebsite.com/myImage3.jpg"" alt = """" style=""width:600px; height: 400px;""/>
                    </div>";

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

        var htmlNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");

        foreach (var node in htmlNodes){

            // Adding class "img-responsive"
            node.AddClass("img-responsive");

            // Removing style attribute
            node.Attributes["style"].Remove();

            Console.WriteLine(node.OuterHtml);
        }

        // Adding the close </img> to each image of the HTML
        HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["img"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;

        // Here you can see the changes in the HTML string
        Console.WriteLine(htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
    }
}
```

You can refer to the Agility Pack HTML documentation here: https://html-agility-pack.net/documentation

This is the link to see the solution running in dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uyhAKE

I hope this work for you.

Comment: Yes, it works. But I have not found how to make "img" tags back to the original document. I will appreciate if you give me a clue on it. I am working to add some validation to the code you provided.

Comment: Hi @user3059248 Add this after the foreach Console.WriteLine(htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml); OuterHtml is going to return you the HTML string with all the changes you apply before in the foreach. I also updated the answer with this change.

Comment: Great. I have noticed that the resulting "img" tags do not end with "/>". Do you think this could cause any errors in browsers?

Comment: Since the <img> tag is the type 'auto close', browsers identify this type of tags and correct if something is wrong. There are a lot of discussions related to this behavior of HTML Agility Pack. Take a look to these discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293342/htmlagilitypack-drops-option-end-tags  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759355/image-tag-not-closing-with-htmlagilitypack/12096383#12096383

Comment: You shouldn't have any issue, the browser is going to render that correctly.

Comment: Also you can try this HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["img"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed; I updated the answer with that code.

Comment: It seems my issue was solved. I appreciate everyone specially user3267053. I would like to share my final code but I do not know where to paste it.

Comment: Thank you @user3059248 can you please vote for my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I do not code in C#, but I am sure this can be done with success using regular expressions and replace with new edited value.